# reverse engineering a camera

Tags: wpf, 3d

If I have a list of 3D points and their 2D projection on screen, is there a way to compute the camera that performed the projection?

I am using the WPF perspective camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the points you have, you should be able to deduce a projection matrix, that actually describes your camera.